# how to detect unexpected element in jaxb

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I use JAXB 2.2.7 to get data from my XML files, the problem is I need to check if there are some unexpected element in my XML files but JAXB don't care and work perfectly without any error.

Example :

```
    <classe> 
  <detail>
        <knowElementFromXSD>value</knowElementFromXSD>
        <unknowElementFromXSD>OtherValue</unknowElementFromXSD>
  </detail>
</classe>
```

For example I need JAXB to throw an error for the  in this XML file because isn't define in my XSD.

If someone have an idea, I can't find any solution on the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways to accomplish your use case:

**Option #1 - `ValidationEventHandler`**

You can set a `ValidationEventHandler` on your Unmarshaller to be notified of things like unexpected elements.  By default a JAXB (JSR-222) implementation will just ignore unmapped elemeents.

**Option #2 - Schema Validation**

If you set an instance of `javax.xml.validation.Schema` on the `Unmarshaller` then the XML input will be validated as it is unmarshalled.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html

Comment: Hi, I forget to say I already use a ValidationEventHandler exactly like in your link. I don't see what add to my validation handler to detect unexpected elements on my unmarshalling.

Comment: In option #1 you say JAXB implementation just ignore unmapped elements by default. So, how can I set the validation handler to detect these unmapped elements ?

Comment: @Wifsimster - The `ValidationEventHandler` will be passed a `ValidationEvent` with a low severity.   The default `ValdatiionEventHandler` won't throw an exception for a low severity.  You can set your own implementation of ‘ValdationEventHandler` on the `Unmarshaller` to change this behaviour.

Comment: Thk for the info, realy help me !